# What are good literature recommendations to understanding attractors?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, neural-networks

I'm a PhD student in Neuroscience working in human physiology. Recently I'm trying to get a better understanding of computational neuroscience as it applies to my field. It is in this context that I am trying to understand attractors. I am in particular looking for literature that explains attractors in a non-mathematical way.

Ideally, I would also like to introspect some MATLAB code that demonstrates a point attractor and a line attractor, to get an intuitive grasp of the basic concepts.

I have read about [Attractors on Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Attractor) in various contexts (e.g. [continuous attractor networks](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Continuous_attractor_network)), but I am having a hard time understanding the role of time in these models.

What are good literature recommendations to understanding attractors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Especially for neuroscientists, I would recommend Izhikevich's book, which you can find in its entirety [here](http://www.izhikevich.org/publications/dsn.pdf). If you're keen on MATLAB, check out [Stephen Lynch's book on the subject](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319068199). This is especially good for an intuitive introduction.

In my opinion, the best high-level book on general dynamical systems is [Guckenheimer and Holmes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387908196), though you may save this one for later.

EDIT: For a good "peek" into the computational neuroscientist's toolbox, I highly recommend [ModelDB](https://senselab.med.yale.edu/modeldb/default.cshtml), a large online database of neural models. For example, I searched "attractor + matlab" on this database and got [these links](https://senselab.med.yale.edu/modeldb/searchFulltext.cshtml?g=attractor%20matlab), some of which may interest you.

Comment: Thanks, the book seems very useful! Just to clarify, I will be collaborating with computational neuroscientists, so I really need not do any modelling in MATLAB. However, it would be interesting to take a peak into a computational neuroscientist's "laboratory". Perhaps you know of any online sources?

Comment: Thanks again! It is really hard to know here to look if you are outside the field. I guess I was too preoccupied with action potentials to register the typo there. :-) [These scripts](https://senselab.med.yale.edu/modeldb/ShowModel.cshtml?model=83517) were exactly what I was looking for! I conclude from the simplest **fixed point** attractor example that timing is abstractly represented and that no 'clock' is needed for simulation.